# SSIS mapping to SQL Server computed column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, calculated-columns, database-administration

Using SQL Server 2014 and SSIS via Visual Studio 2015.

Source and Destination are both SQL Server dbs located on the same server.  Destination table has 2 columns that are computed at the table.

The values for these columns are NOT being determined via the Derived Column feature of SSIS.  The values for these columns are computed by the destination db on the destination table.

On the destination mapping editor, these two columns have the input column set to `<ignore>.`

When I run the package, I'm getting an error because the package is attempting to insert nulls into the computed columns.

I've tried running it with Check constraints checked and unchecked.  I do not want to uncheck the Keep Nulls box because much of the source data is legitimately null.

Any suggestions on how to load a table with computed columns?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to insert values that cause the computation to be null, you probably need to extract your logic for your computed columns, then apply this to the source data, and see which rows end up with the expression returning null.

Comment: @GarethD That makes sense, but it doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem.  I'm using a select statement that works via SSMS without causing any errors at the target.

Comment: @Tod Meinke Have you tried setting the columns in the destination mapping to <ignore>? (At least that is what I would do in SSIS 2008).

Comment: @rafaelbattesti Yes, they are set to ignore.  I just realized my original post ignored the ingore tag.  I just fixed it...

Comment: @Tod Meinke What kind of information are you trying to add to these columns? If you could share a bit more on the logic you are using, maybe we could spot the problem. I.e. how are you inserting the rows? Are you using a stored procedure? Would it make sense to place the logic to insert the values for the 2 columns in a trigger?

Comment: @rafaelbattesti The insert is a select statement that works via T-SQL. Doing it that way, I just ignore the computed columns.  So, for example, if the destination has a computed column named Age and another column named Person, it would be: insert into DestinationTable (Person) select Person from SourceTable.

Comment: @Tod Meinke I see what you mean. Your process to populate the destination table and to insert into the 2 columns are separate processes. First you transfer everything you need to the destination table and after you run the insert, is that correct?

Comment: @rafaelbattesti There is only one step in the process.  SQL Server performs the column computation on its own much in the same way it will generate an ID for an identity column.  IOW, you just ignore these columns when doing an insert.

Comment: If you don't have anything mapped to these columns then it must be the formula defined in them that is causing the error. I've never had problems inserting into a table with calculated columns in SSIS (not that I recall). Can you please post the actual error as it may clarify the issue further. Can you also post he calcs in the columns

Comment: Agree with Nick, we need to see the complete, exact error message you are getting.

Comment: @TabAlleman  I reworked the package this morning by recreating smaller pieces of the table and select statement. I got it to work, naturally, and then scaled it all the way up to the full transformation and it's still working. Unfortunately, I don't have the original package from yesterday so I can only guess that I must have had an error in the select statement that might have been generating a misleading error message in the SSIS. debugger.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I couldn't tag 2 users, so please see the above post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing something similar, I have to ask if your error message said "String or binary data would be truncated"?

This wouldn't have been due to a NULL insert into a computed column, since you set the input column to `<ignore>`, just as you would for an autoincrement identity column in the destination table.

Instead, this looks like an intermittent SSIS bug where an OLE DB Destination in a Dataflow tries to insert into a table with computed columns, and fails.  Intermittent, because small changes made the problem appear for me;  and small changes made it disappear for you.

If you run into this problem again:  please make a copy of the destination table without the computed column(s) and insert records through a new OLE DB Destination.  If this works, you're looking at the "SSIS Destination Computed Column Bug".

For more on the multitude of sins covered by the "String or binary data would be truncated" message, see https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name .  It documents a decade of Microsoft ignoring the problem, despite 1610 upvotes.

UPDATE:  The easiest workaround is to use a regular table load instead of fast load in the OLE DB Destination component in the Dataflow.  This is a known Microsoft bug, a.k.a. "BCP and BULK INSERT fail on computed table columns (they don't skip computed columns)".

But just try to follow this link now and see what you get:  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2779032/bcp-and-bulk-insert-fail-on-computed-table-columns-they-dont-skip-computed-columns .  Yes, they've "retired" it to hide the evidence.